# realm predicate with an object inside object

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have the following Realm Objects

```
class Patient: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    let list = List<RString>()
}

class RString: Object {

    @objc dynamic var stringValue: String?

}
```

I need to filter `Patient` objects that have an `RString` component in List with `stringValue = "test"`

Is something like this possible?

```
patients = realm?.objects(Patient.self).filter("name = 'name1' AND @% IN list", RString(stringValue: 'test'))
```

Comment: Is this a really simplified example or are you actually just trying to filter a `List` of `String`s? Since for a while now, `List` supports storing non-`Object` subclasses as well, so you can simply define `let list = List<String>()`.

Comment: this is a simplified example, the class RString contains other variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `SUBQUERY` to be able to access the properties of the elements of a `List` in an `NSPredicate`. The `SUBQUERY` will evaluate `true` for every `Patient` whose `list` property includes at least 1 `RString` element whose `stringValue` matches the provided `String`.

```
patients = realm?.objects(Patient.self).filter("name = %@ AND SUBQUERY(list,$element,$element.stringValue == %@).@count>0", "name1", "test")
```